# Client server that is compatible with Laravel 5.x

Tags: php, rest, laravel, server, client

Now I'm making a queuing system that connect between the server (Apache PHP) and client (Android native). They communicates with Restful Web Service because Restful support for multi-platform communication.

But now I need to show the queue in the LED TV 32 inch to display the current queue.

The flow is :

1. User (on Android) request the queue number to server.
2. Server return the queue number to User (on Android). Communicate with Restful Web Service.
3. At the same time, server showing the queue number that user request on monitor LED TV 32 inch.

**Is there a way to make a point no 3 ??** Because I made a system with PHP Laravel 5.2 and I know the PHP does not support client server side.

Does anyone have any ideas about this case?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this. You have two options, Long Polling or Websockets. You will just need to write a frontend in HTML/CSS/JS to display.

Or if you wanted to go super simple you could use default Laravel view system Blade and just have the browser refresh every 5 or 10 seconds.